# check route url on cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Hi all i have a menu like this on a cakephp 2 website:

```
<ul class="nav">
<li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Home', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index')); ?></li>
<li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Add post', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'add')); ?></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

and i have to check if i'm on a page to add class="selected" on the menu link.
How can i do this?

Thanks

Comment: i think you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, it will give you current page's url, not tested

Comment: what cakephp version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

In your view file you can also do:

```
$this->request->params
```

I recommend you to write your own helper that will implement a method with the same args as HtmlHelper::link and internally call and return HtmlHelper but before it will compare $this->request->params with the passed array of the first arg. If it matches you can inject the class name in the 3rd arg.

Something like this, implement it on your own:

```
class MyHelper extends AppHelper {
    public $helpers = array('Html');
    public function link($title, $url, $options) {
    /** 
     * if ($this->View->request->params ...
     * do your matching logic here
     * and if it matches: $options['class'] = 'active';
     */
    return $this->Html->link($title, $url, $options
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a (CakePHP 1.2) helper a while back that does this automatically:

http://richardathome.com/blog/cakephp-smarter-links

Should be pretty straight forward to port it to 2.0